Is there the possibility to use dataChangeFilterDeadbandType and dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue in multitag acquisition by Apache Camel OPC UA CLIENT?
I'm using Apache Camel OPC UA client to acquire tags (signals) value from Industrial Gateway OPCUA Server.
My target is to try to acquire a set of tags value with a sampling interval and define for each tag a  DeadbandType (dataChangeFilterDeadbandType) and DeadbandValue (dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue) filter. Reading Apache Camel OPC UA client documentation for read values from nodes section looks like that the deadband setting for each tags is not possible by keys configuration.
Currently as frameworks I'm using
Spring Boot with Apache Camel OPC UA client component 3.22.2 LTS version.
I'm able to acquire tags value with the following code snippet:
from("quartz://myjob?cron=0/1+*+*+*+*+?")
.setHeader("CamelMiloNodeIds", constant(Arrays.asList("ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA",
"ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_VAH")))
            .setHeader("await", constant(true)) // await: parameter "defaultAwaitWrites"
            .enrich("milo-client:opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?
keyStoreUrl=file:C:\\Temp\\application\\certificate\\clientkeystore.jks
&keyPassword=123456
&keyStorePassword=123456
&applicationUri=urn:8409:test:camelopcua
&applicationName=camelopcua", 
new AggregationStrategy() {
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
   LOGGER.info(newExchange.getMessage().getBody());
   return newExchange; 
}

The following timeseries data that I'm getting in the body message:
[
DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1601}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133639511988350613, javaDate=Thu Jun 27 08:39:58 UTC 2024}},DataValue{value=Variant{value=true}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1601}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133639511988350613, javaDate=Thu Jun 27 08:39:58 UTC 2024}}
]

My question is:
Is there the way to define DeadbandType and DeadbandValue for each tag by using Camel OPCUA keys configuration ?
